# redirect a specific request to a subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a laravel application installed in the root folder of the web directory. so for e.g https://www.example.com is handled by Laravel. However i need to deploy a second application in a subfolder of the root directory. The second application is deployed in a folder named tasks. So for e.g

```
laravel-application
 --- tasks
```

What i want is to access the tasks directory by visiting https://www.example.com/tasks. And let the main laravel application be available at https://www.example.com How do i make changes to the .htaccess to ensure it. A subdomain is not viable at this point. The laravel site is deployed in the root folder.

Thanks in advance